# Android Htc Eris

Tags: android

Hi
 i have developed an application and it smoothly running in all phones except Htc Eris, in Htc Eris i get out of memory exception, null pointer exception etc, but these problem i never see in my samsung galaxy or motrolloz milestone or spice mobile, i need to know any problem in Htc Eris, like low memory ,low processing power etc

Comment: There's no question or no information.

Comment: Can't help but I'm also having issues specifically with the Eris. Crashes whenever it tries to load the FMOD library. This works fine on a dozen other phones though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Heap Size" on the Htc Eris's factory ROM is at 16M and the other phones are 24M and higher.

You need to try to optimize your application as best as possible so it cam run on the phones with a smaller heap ( ..or virtual memory - similar to the virtual disc size on Windows).  A good place to start and easiest is to optimize all your drawables and don't put any PNG's in the drawable folder; these images are not compressed at run time like the other drawable folders. ie. drawable-hdpi.  I discovered this by accident when I but a wallpaper in that folder - I was getting the same errors as you. Moving the PNG to the /drawable-hdpi folder alone cleared it.